# Remove "rugby-union" synonym for "rugby"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At some point, it seems that [rugby-union](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rugby-union) has been marked as a synonym of [rugby](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rugby). I'd suggest that this change should be reversed, and we should have three separate tags:

- [rugby](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rugby): for general questions about rugby which cross both union and league
- [rugby-union](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rugby-union): for union specific questions
- [rugby-league](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rugby-league): for league specific questions

As an example of a question which I think would be improved by this, see [Rugby penalty kick into touch-in-goal](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/rugby-penalty-kick-into-touch-in-goal) - that's absolutely a union-specific question, and the answer will be significantly different for league. Yet the only thing we can tag it with is [rugby](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rugby) which includes league as part of its definition.

See also: [Should the Rugby tag be removed - replaced with just Rugby-Union and Rugby-League?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163/should-the-rugby-tag-be-removed-replaced-with-just-rugby-union-and-rugby-leagu), although that's from 2012.

Comment: OK. this now has four upvotes and nobody saying "don't do this", so I'm taking it as a general sign of consensus. However, I don't believe this is something I can do with my limited powers - mods, is this something you can help with?

Comment: `rugby` and `rugby-union` have been desynonymized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, @edmastermind29 has removed the synonym. My work here is done (although we should probably consider retagging some questions).

Comment: Feel free to flag some questions with the retagging request and I will gladly retag.

Comment: I can retag them - it's just a matter of time :-)